# How to convert a less file to CSS file in DotLess and put it into a specified directory

Tags: css, web-config, less, dotless

In most of LESS compilers, it's possible to use compiler to convert a `.less` file to a `.css` file. It's also possible to determine the output directory via some kind of configuration.

Is it possible to do the same in DotLess? How should I do it?

What I'm after is something similar to this configuration:

```
<dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false" />
    <lessFile source='/content/example.less' target='/content/example.css' />
</dotless>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) site there is a quick usage guide.  Essentially, if you have set up Dotless in your project, you just need to reference the less files in your web pages, as you would a css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bacon.less">
```

Dotless will then convert the less to css for you via the http handler.